# How to configure Postfix for Mojave?

Tags: postfix-mta, macos-mojave

I'm trying to get Postfix working on my Mojave system but it doesn't start.

I created a sasl_passwd file and edited the main.cf file.

By starting postfix in the terminal I get the message

postfix/postfix-script: fatal: mail system startup failed

I have no idea how to get it working.

Anybody idea's how to do?